# How can I replace custom tags with strings from an xlf file in TYPO3

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.x

I'm trying to use the TYPO3 [tags](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/Functions/Tags/Index.html) function to get strings from an xlf file. If I hard code the reference to the string I want, it returns successfully, but I need to know how to get it to return the appropriate string based on the tag content.

For example, this works:

HTML:

```
<var>myVar</var>
```

Typoscript:

```
lib.parseFunc_myExt{
    tags {
        var = TEXT
        var{
            value = {LLL:path/to/locallang.xlf:var.myVar}
            insertData = 1
        }
    }
}
```

I need a method to take the content of the `<var>` tag and use it in place of `myVar` in the value.

Comment: What are you actually trying to archive? This sounds more like a hacky workaround.

Comment: I have several strings (mostly numbers) which need to be repeated in blocks of text throughout my site. I want to define them in one place, so I can change them and have the change applied throughout the site.

Comment: The easiest might be to write on own little php function for this and do this kind of post processing after the page generation (there are hooks for this).